# Django MSSQL Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tblSORequestFromEmail' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql-server, django

When I run this on an external database

```py
SORequestFromEmail.objects.create(subject='test')
```

I get this error, why is that?

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tblSORequestFromEmail' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I was not even specifying a value for the ID in the query, see below for model definition

```py
class SORequestFromEmail(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
    fromemail = models.TextField(db_column='FromEmail', blank=True)
    fromname = models.TextField(db_column='FromName', blank=True)
    subject = models.TextField(db_column='Subject', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(db_column='TextDescription', blank=True)
    cc = models.TextField(db_column='CC', blank=True)
    datetimereceived = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateTimeReceived')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tblSORequestFromEmail'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ahhh, it needs to be an `AutoField` for the id field

```py
class SORequestFromEmail(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID')
```